# How do I get more mannequins?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, mods

Is it possible for me to add mannequins through the console in some way or form?  Or is there a mod that lets me place and buy them?

Comment: As to a Mod, give it a few weeks. The Construction Kit isn't even out yet, so the player housing revamps that there will surely be dozens of haven't even been started in on yet...

Comment: Yup your just going to have to wait like the rest of us for the construction set. Once that is released you will be able to build rooms full of mannequins and anything else your heart desires. Bethblog.com has stated its release will be in Jan 2012.

Comment: He did state CONSOLE not PC so the tool kit wouldnt help if i understood his question...
i do wish they would release the Martha Stewart Mod so those of us on 360 could Mod our houses as well : )
and i do mean by not having to have Modded the box or Modding the save/hex or gaming files

Comment: He meant the PC version, and for that you would need the code for the mannequin, which I have not been able to find, then use "Player.placeatme *code*" command. That should place it where you are facing. This works for all furniture codes.

Comment: @Master69Wraith he stated console as in in-game command line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short answer**: Wait for a mod.

**Long answer**: You can sort of wing it with with the console.

SAVE BEFORE YOU DO THIS IN CASE YOU DON'T LIKE THE RESULTS.

1. Jump. Open the console mid-jump.
2. `player.placeatme 89a85 1`

This creates a *living* mannequin NPC at your location. Did you know mannequins are actually NPCs with disabled animations? Creepy. Unfortunately, there is no way to attach the special script that mannequins have to the NPC you just created using the console. However:

First, open the console, click on the mannequin so that it's ID is shown:

- The `tai` command will disable AI for the mannequin.
- The `openactorcontainer 1` command will show you the inventory
- The `sexchange` command will flip the gender.

Note that since the mannequin lacks whatever mannequin script the real implementations use you will **have** to use `openactorcontainer 1` to change out the inventory. In addition, weapons don't seem to show up on mannequins added this way.

You do this at your own risk, as we have no idea what kind of black magic the mannequin script contains to protect your items, make the weapons display, etc. The console is really for *debugging* the game, not *editing* the game.

[Source](http://www.thenexusforums.com/index.php?/topic/482475-tutorial-spawn-a-mannequin-base-id-89a85/).

Comment: That is creepy, although from Bethesda's perspective it's a pretty elegant solution.  There's something appealingly twisted about a character using magically frozen people to hang clothes on.

Comment: this has been the way its been done in mods since morrowind, so I'm not too surprised they stuck with it.  It is creepy though.

Comment: TAI can break some characters and they wont speak when you interact with them, you need to use TAI again or your camera will act as if you are in conversation